# How to determine the number of users to use in Jmeter performance testing?

Tags: performance, jmeter

This can actually be a complex question for me, if the number is not given directly from my product owner as a direct requirement.

Jmeter is basically an API performance testing tool. I've seen so many Jmeter scripts that include only the important APIs needed for the flow to be tested. It does not consider any pure front end (UI) related user actions.

A common reply to my question in article/tutorial is: estimate how many concurrent users you normally have on your website?

The problem with this approach is that user purely browsing your website is not causing any 'load' that Jmeter try to simulate.

If user is using a form submission webpage for example, every second user uses to browse the page content, or filling the data in the form are pure front end (UI) activity and does not lead to any 'load'. There may be 10 concurrent user visiting my webpage, but only 2 are 'submitting'. Should i use 10 or 2 in this scenario? The Jmeter script is intended to only measure the performance of 'submit form' API.

Another most sophisticated reply to my question is 'load testing calculator' mentioned in https://www.webperformance.com/library/tutorials/CalculateNumberOfLoadtestUsers.

It calculate concurrent number of user from 'visit rate (visits/hour)' and 'Average visit length (minutes/visit)'. This is more precise that the 1st reply of just 'estimate how many concurrent users are using your system?'.

However it has the same issue as the 1st reply in that it does not define 'Average visit length (minutes/visit)' as 'Average visit length' from API perspective. The same argument i present for the form submission website applies here too. The 'visit' time a user spend on browsing the page, filling the form does not count, only the time he spend on 'submit form' API does.

So what's your way of determining the number of users to use in Jmeter test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Jmeter is basically an API performance testing tool.` - this is wrong

Think of each JMeter thread (virtual user) as of the real user with all its attributes like:

- [using a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
- needing some time to ["think" between operations](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)

Once you implement your JMeter test so each JMeter virtual user represents a real user with 100% accuracy - you will be able to tell how many users your website can handle without issues by looking at i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) chart.

If you need to know how many requests per second are X virtual users making - check out [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) chart.

Comment: this is really helpful. I am still seeing may jmeter script removing resource retrieving actions like GET https://www.xxx.com.au/content/dam/ubankcap/images/cancel.svg items, and only keep the 'backbone' APIs that their own company implement. Even third party cross domain APIs are removed from Jmeter script. It seems like a common practice now

Comment: also could you shed some light on the topic 'how to estimate the number of user to USE in performance testing'. Sorry my original post title is misleading. I know to find the actual number of user from Jmeter report. what i ask is how to find out what's the right number of user to set as Jmeter thread group parameter.